# c# как при создании ярлыка указать иконку другого файла

Tags: c#

К примеру через `IWshRuntimeLibrary` ярлык создается так:

```
public static void CreateLinkOnDesctop(string SourceFile, string IcoFileName, string LinkName, string ToolTip)
        {
            WshShell = new WshShellClass();
            IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut MyShortcut;
            MyShortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)WshShell.CreateShortcut(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)+"\\"+LinkName+".lnk");
            MyShortcut.TargetPath = SourceFile;
            MyShortcut.Description = ToolTip;
            MyShortcut.IconLocation = IcoFileName;
            MyShortcut.Save();
        }
```

И указать иконку тут можно `MyShortcut.IconLocation = IcoFileName;`, но для этого требуется путь к конкретной картинке. Можно ли как-нибудь программно вытащить иконку другого файла и использовать её?

Comment: `System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("FileName");` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, допустим есть у нас этот объект  `var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(patch);`. Дальше что? Сохранять его в качестве отдельного файла и потом использовать.. Или как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вопрос (который указан в "теле" вашего поста)

> Можно ли как-нибудь программно вытащить иконку другого файла и использовать её?

Ответ я вам дал уже в комментариях, это вызвать метод [System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon(v=vs.110).aspx), который вернет вам объект изображения, дальше можете что угодно с ним делать.

А вот на вопрос (который в название почему то (чего я очень не люблю))...

> как при создании ярлыка указать иконку другого файла

Ответ простой, задайте путь к файлу, который содержит изображение и через запятую укажите номер картинки:

```
shortcut.IconLocation = @"C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll,1";
```

или вон, я от Fallout 4 поставил:

```
shortcut.IconLocation = @"D:\Games\Fallout 4\Fallout4.exe,0";
```